# What would be the charge distribution in a Klein bottle?

Tags: electrostatics

We know that for any conductor the charge lies on the outer surface at electrostatic equilibrium. What would happen if a [Klein bottle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle) is made up of a conductor and a charge is placed on it?

Comment: You cannot make a conductor that is truly non-orientable (such as a Klein bottle) in three dimensions.

Comment: Is that due to the finite thickness of the bottle's walls?

Comment: No, a true Klein bottle has walls of thickness zero. Even approximating this using walls of finite thickness, you still need the walls to intersect themselves in an impossible manner (i.e by passing through some higher dimension). This happens for real (mathematical), 2D Klein bottles too.

Comment: So that means those glass bottles advertised as Klein bottles technically aren't? Because those could easily be made out of a conducting material.

Comment: @andynitrox, they are meant to represent 3d projections of the higher dimensional Klein bottles. And yes, technically they aren't Klein bottles.